# What does variable++ and variable-- mean?

Tags: c#

I know that `++variable` adds 1 to the variable, but what about `variable++` and `variable--`?

Comment: `--` just subtracts.  The other difference is what the expression returns `variable++` returns the value before it is incremented and `++variable` returns the value after.  If used on a line by itself it doesn't matter, but if you do `while(variable-- > 0)` that will be different from `while(--variable > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

These are [increment and decrement operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).  The positioning of the operators with relation to the variable governs the order in which the operation is applied.

`var++` returns the variable's value and then increments it by one
`++var` first increments the variable by one and then returns the newly incremented value

similarly...

`var--` returns the variable's value and then decrements it by one
`--var` first decrements the variable value and then returns the newly decremented value

Comment: Actually `var++` saves to a temp variable, then increments `var`, then returns the temp variable.  The return does not happen before the increment.

Comment: @juharr that may be the case, however I thought, given the question, that the finer details were probably not necessary.  I updated my answer to avoid any confusion.